# Understanding the while loop condition in how to find the middle node in a linked list

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

I don't fully understand the `while` loop condition for the ["find the middle of linked list"](https://leetcode.com/problems/middle-of-the-linked-list/) question on leetcode:

> Given a non-empty, singly linked list with head node head, return a middle node of linked list.
>
> If there are two middle nodes, return the second middle node.

For the `while` loop, I thought the condition would be

```
while first and last.next:
```

But when I do that, I receive an error that says

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'
```

The condition statement is supposed to be

```
while last and last.next:
```

I don't understand why. Here is the entire code with the correct while loop:

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.next = None

class Solution(object):
    def middleNode(self, head):
        first = last = head
        while last and last.next:
            first = first.next
            last = last.next.next
        return first
```

Comment: If `last` is `None` (i.e. you are at the end of the linked list) you are supposed to end the loop, that's why. `first` can never become equal to `None` before `last` does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea behind the algorithm is that you don't know where the end of the list is. However, if you step one pointer twice as fast as the other, it will reach the end just as the other reaches the middle.

The initialization sets the middle (`first`) and end (`last`) pointers to the only thing you know initially: the start of the list. The body of the loop steps them forward: `first = first.next` moves one step ahead while `last = last.next.next` moves two steps ahead. Since `last` is always ahead of `first`, the is no need to check if `first` can move forward. Instead, the condition of the loop checks that both of the references used in stepping `last` are non-`None`: `while last and last.next:`.

Notice that if the list has one element, `last` will not move since `last.next` is `None`. However, with two elements, `last` will move, and so will `first`. The result is that the condition for picking the second middle from a list with an even number of elements is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Just draw it out and it will be obvious. Consider both versions:

A - B - C

```
first / last / last.next
A       B      C  
B       None
```

A - B - C - D

```
first / last / last.next
A       B      C  
B       D      None
```